# Lucky Egg timing for increasing friendship level?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'd like to use a Lucky Egg right before my friendship with another player levels so I double the significant XP boost. How do I time it so that I trigger the level with when the Lucky Egg is active? I'm guessing I would do it this way:

1. Wait until friendship shows "Play together for 1 more days to be come X Friends"
2. Wait until friend has sent gift (but don't open yet)
3. (Optionally) wait until 1 and 2 is true for lots of friends
4. Use Lucky Egg
5. Open friend's gift *and* send them a gift before Lucky Egg timer ends

If I do it this way will it ensure that the friendship levels while the Lucky Egg is active?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to guarantee the timing on when you increase the level, then do the following:

1. Exchange gifts with your friend until it says "Play together for 2 more days to become X friends"

   - See instructions below on how to find this message
2. Send your friend *one more gift and no more*. Once they open it, the counter will change to "1 more day".
3. Wait for your friend to send you a gift but ***do not open it***! Do not send your friend *any more gifts* or they may inadvertently trigger the levelling at the wrong time.
4. (Optional) Repeat 1-3 for several other friends if you want to level several at the same time to save on lucky eggs.
5. You're ready to level the friendship. Set an exact time and date when you're going to open their next gift and level the friendship.
6. Be nice! Contact your friend outside of the app (if you can) and let them know exactly when you'll be opening their gift so they can use a lucky egg if they want to get the experience bonus.
7. Use a lucky egg
8. Open all the gifts from all your friends that are "1 day" from leveling and enjoy tons of double experience!

## Finding Current Friendship Days Counter

1. Tap on your profile photo in the lower left
2. Select the "Friends" tab
3. Tap on your friend
4. Tap on your friendship level heart meter

[image]

5. Tap on the next empty friendship level heart

[image]

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is start the lucky egg before either of you open a gift on that day.  Once one person open a gift both people get the experience.

Comment: I don't always have control over when a friend might open their gift, that's why I thought step 2 might be necessary - it prevents my friend from triggering the level increase before I start the lucky egg.

Comment: Yes it is required to do that but the other person might try to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

If you are not in control of the Best Friend level-up timing because:

- The timer has said 'play together for 1 more day' since yesterday or even longer
- Your friend has your unopened gift, but you have no gift from your friend
- You don't have any way to communicate (remote friend, different time zone, etc)

This worked for me:

- I remembered the name of the friend in control.
- As soon as I opened the game, I immediately went to News: (click the ball, press 'News' in the upper right corner....Hurry!)
- I saw that the friend had opened my gift a few hours ago.
- I quickly pressed 'Items' and activated a lucky egg.
  Right after that, I got the Best Friend notification and 200,000 XP points (100,000 plus an additional 100,000 for the lucky egg)

This also worked for me:

- Compete in raid with friend, which raised us to Best Friend status, and it even said so in the screen before the 'catch' event.
- I had no active lucky egg though.
- I completed the catch, then immediately activated a lucky egg. When message for the update to my XP arrived, it was 200,000.

Comment: I can confirm, that the mentioned method works. It.seems like that the XP is only calculated after you received the notification. As long as the notification is not/can not be retrieved (e.g. because of a bad internet connection or you skip through the menu) the notification does not appear.

Comment: This no longer works. As soon as you click 'OK' on the warning screen (when you open the game) the friendship upgrade notification is already there. You can't get to the items menu fast enough. I confirmed this with two separate attempts.